# google maps streetview controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

Okay, I've been working on this project where I want to manually control navigation inside a Google Map StreetView Map, so not through any built in features such as streetviewcontrols. I have been able to manually navigate the roadMap through map.panBY(x,y) but this doesn't work in the streetview.

Let says for argument sake a I want 3 buttons: "left" "right" "forward" below my map to control the navigation.  I can't seem to find out what functions to place inside these button onclick functions.  I somewhat understand I need to fool around with the POV but not really sure how.  Any help/ insight would be much appreciated.

NOTE** I am using the pegman to access the StreetView Map ie: map.getStreetView();

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question but you cannot pan to a position like you do in map..
Street View is set of linked StreetView Panorama, so you change the visible panorama.. So each panorama will have links to other panoramas..
What you can do inside a panorama is turn left/right/up/down the view.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing it seems like the actions you want to do with these buttons are pretty much what you get by clicking the arrow keys on your keyboard. If that assumption is correct, maybe you can just get away with simulating/triggering keydown-events on the map element? I guess you should be able to use jQuery for this.